# jquery ajaxform global functions

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

We are using the [jQuery form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#getting-started) on our site. We need to be able to show a loading gif when a submit occurs on all forms. So far I have been able to get this done like the following

```
    $("#uploadAssetImageForm").ajaxForm({
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSubmit: function () {Cvrs.SetLoading(true, '#uploadAssetImageForm')},
        success: function(asset) {
            Cvrs.SetLoading(false, '#uploadAssetImageForm');
        $("#uploadAssetImageDiv").dialog("close");
            $(":input", "#uploadAssetImageDiv").not(':button, :submit, :reset').val('').removeAttr('checked').removeAttr('selected');
            ReplaceAsset(asset);

        }
    });
```

In particular the parts I'm talking about are the beforeSubmit function and the call again to set it to false on success.

Set loading just shows a loading gif and disabled form buttons

```
function(isLoading, form) {

isLoading ? $(form + ' input[type="submit"]').attr("disabled", true) :
    $(form + ' input[type="submit"]').removeAttr("disabled");


isLoading ? $(form + ' .loading-animation').show() :
    $(form + ' .loading-animation').hide();
```

Is there any way I can get any call to ajaxform to run that code on the beforeSubmit and success along with any other code that might be there as well (running the loading stuff first though) or do I have to go through each case and add this in?

I understand I'll have to put the loading reference in each form but this makes sense as its possible that different forms could need the loading gif in different spots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may consider using the [ajaxSend](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSend/) event. It fires before an AJAX send event is fired:

```
$(document).bind('ajaxSend', function(e, request, options) {
    Cvrs.SetLoading(true, '#uploadAssetImageForm');
});
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: I'd need to tie that back to the form somehow though so I only active the loading gif in that one form, maybe those parameters give me access to the information, will take a look

Comment: @DanielPowell You could bind directly to the form instead of the document, which may work depending on you plan to tie back in.

Comment: Seems like even if i tie it directly to the form when another ajax request happens in the page it will enable it in the form, need a way to specify only ajax requests happening from within the forms (they have different urls unfortunately)